# Remove duplicates from select

Tags: php

I have a php foreach statement that is showing data into a select box as options.

My data is a list of names that the user has linked to their account.

for ex:

```
Name        Year
Dave        1900
John        1902
Adam        1903
Dave        1803
```

so the Name is the same, but the years are different.

I am wondering if there is a possible way in the foreach statement to only print "Dave" once even though Dave is in the database multiple times.

Comment: do it in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in the SQL query ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM mytable ORDER BY name
```

But if you need to do it in PHP for some reason ...

```
$select_names = [];
foreach($all_names as $name) {
    if ( ! in_array($name, $select_names) ) {
        $select_names[] = $name;
    }
}
sort($select_names);
```